# Design for RAMDisk file system?

Tags: c, filesystems, persistence

I am writing a RAMDisk (A filesystem in RAM with overall size less than 10 MB) as a part of my project. It should work just like a normal file system by allocating blocks of size 4KB in RAM. I am free to choose any design such as FAT, ext4 etc. The only issue is I need to persist this file system and read it back from disk when I restart my program later.

I want to know what is the best design to write such kind of a file system considering two important aspects in mind.

1. It is very small (10 MB max - Not more than 500 files)
2. All structures (metadata) will contains pointers and I need to persist everything to hard disk.

What is the best design for such a file system?

Comment: The best design in terms of what ?

Comment: This question seems way too broad.